# Liquibase best practice to setup for multi Schema/Database repository on different environments

Tags: oracle, liquibase, liquibase-cli

Suppose I have below repo with folder structure with changelog and properties files-

```
    projectRepo/
        DB_A/changelog.xml
        DB_B/changelog.xml
        DB_C/changelog.xml
      masterChangelog.xml
      liquibase.properties
```

- Above we have 3 DB folders(A,B,C) and masterChangelog.xml file calls the changelog presented inside different DB folders.
- And let's say we have 3 Environments - DEV, STAGING and PROD.
- Now in order to run any liquibase command(ex: update), how the changelog and properties files should be structured?
- Goal is achive by running single command like - **liquibase update --changeLogFile=masterChangelog.xml**, but username and password of all DB are different and that too will change based on the environment.

  - For ex: credentials for DB_A is different in DEV, STAGING and PROD.
  - credentials for DB_B(differs from DB_A) is also different in different environments.
  - Same for DB_C

**Any help to suggest best practice or solution to be followed?**